# How to get username if macros are disabled?

Tags: ms-access, macros, vba

I would like to set startup properties for Access 2010 accrding to permission level of the user. For example, I have in the dtb table with the user list and their permissions. According this I would like to hide Navigation pane etc. for standard users, and show for admins. The user names are based on API user name. But the VBA function getting username does not work within AutoExec macro if the user didn't allow macros after Access startup.

How could I manage this? Thanks

Martin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Environment variables contain things such as username, computer name, default file paths to temp folder etc

```
Environ("username")
Environ("computername")
Environ("temp")
```

**Edit:**

Place the VBA function below in a module

```
Public Function CurrentUsername() As String
    CurrentUsername = Environ("username")
End Function
```

Then in your macro you will refer to `CurrentUsername()` whenever you want to compare it to something (if you want to use `SetTempVars` you'll have to modify the variable to output with quotes)

Comment: I tried this but I got an error "the expression you entered has a function name that Microsoft Access can't find." I used simple condition - If Environ("username") <> "AdminName" Then....

Comment: Seems like you have to get a bit more creative to user environment variables in a macro.  Editing answer to show what worked for me.

Comment: Thanks, this is clear for me, but I need to receive username within AutoExec. Because if the user does not allow macros after startup the VBA code will be blocked.

Comment: Or other approach - at the startup open blank form with instructions to "Allow macros" and when performed, then open the database. Is it possible to check, if macros are allowed?